# How to make randomly sampled training sets of proportionately equal sizes?

Tags: r

I want to make a series of randomly sampled training sets that are exactly 75% the size of the full data set. The code below is an example of what I want to achieve except I always want 75 samples of 1, and 25 samples of 2; this code only gives me samples which are close to those sizes but not exact.

```
column <- c(rep("A", 40), rep("B", 60))
data <- as.data.frame(column)            
index <- sample(2,100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.75,0.25))
```

I want to be able to achieve this kind of partitioning without the use of additional packages and just with the base R if possible. Packages don't seem to work for me the vast majority of the time, which is why I have found it difficult to find a solution already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how `sample` is intended to work. You may instead consider two steps:

```
idxTrain <- sample(100, 75)
head(idxTrain)
# [1] 54 70  3 42 72 67
length(idxTrain)
# [1] 75
idxTest <- setdiff(1:100, idxTrain)
head(idxTest)
# [1]  5  7 13 14 19 24
length(idxTest)
# [1] 25
```